# react-router v4 prevent render parent if sidebar component is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used `react-router v4` to make sidebar component like this:

```
  <ParentComponent>
    {routes.map((route, index) => (
      <Route
        key={index}
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        component={route.sidebar}
      />
    ))}
  </ParentComponent>
```

And the routes are

```
[
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    sidebar: HomeSideBar,
    mobileSidebar: HomeSideBar,
    component: HomePage,
  },{
    path: '/profile',
    exact: true,
    mobileSidebar: HomeSideBar,
    component: ProfilePage,
  }, {
    path: '/*',
    component: NotFound,
  },
]
```

And I tried to not render parent `<ParentComponent>` in case i don't have `sidebar` in routes, it means if the `component={route.sidebar}` in map doesn't exist, the `<ParentComponent>` not rendered.
I tried to check by `routes.length` or `ref` but it's not work. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks for any answer.